# CertificateStore's Certificates.Find() doesn't actually find the certificate

Tags: c#, certificate

Here's my simple method:

```cs
private static X509Certificate2 GetCertificateFromStore(StoreLocation storeLocation, string certName) {
    var store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    try {
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, certName, true);
        return certs.Count == 0 ? null : certs[0];
    }
    finally {
        store.Close();
    }
}
```

Debug locals show that `store.Certificates` has been loaded and contains two certificates — the default "localhost" one and one I've imported, so the correct store has been successfully opened.

However, the `Find()` method always returns an empty result, regardless of which certificate I search for and whether I use `FindBySubjectName` or `FindByThumbprint`.

Any ideas what could be wrong? It is a simple console app created for the sole purpose of learning & testing certificate loading, i.e., virtually nothing in project configuration or anywhere else is other than default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try false as your third parameter to the store.Certificates.Find() method - its possible your your certificates are not valid and are being excluded.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly it! :) Though it baffles me a bit that a built-in, default certificate added by Windows itself would be invalid.

Comment: What exactly does "valid" mean? All of my certificates are considered not to be valid, but examining them using the Windows certificate manager indicates all certificates are OK.